# Meteor signature pad upload data uri

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, data-uri

I am creating a simple app in Meteor that requires a user signature. I would like to upload the captured signature and then retrieve the url/data and display it in another part of the app.

I have the following packages installed:

• CollectionFS

• GridFS

• SignaturePad

I also have a collection called Signatures and the following Meteor code so far:

```
Template.signin.events({
'click [data-action=save]': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert('Please provide signature first');
    } else {
        var file = signaturePad.toDataURL();

        Signatures.insert(file);
    }
}
});
```

I have the following HTML in my template:

```
<template name="signin">
<div id="signature-pad" class="m-signature-pad row">
    <div class="m-signature-pad--body col-md-12">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="m-signature-pad--footer col-md-12">
        <div class="description">Sign above</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-action="save">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

This is saving a record to Mongo but I cannot see a reference to the link/image string anywhere, here's what I see in the Chrome Inspector:

```
_id: "NowB4cZBckgE92rY3"
collectionName: "signatures"
copies: Object
signatures: Object
createdAt: Wed Nov 04 2015 13:37:36 GMT+0000 (GMT)
key: "563a0a201b3eb0cb0431f472"
name: null
size: 19089
type: "image/png"
updatedAt: Wed Nov 04 2015 13:37:36 GMT+0000 (GMT)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
createdByTransform: true
original: Object
uploadedAt: Wed Nov 04 2015 13:37:36 GMT+0000 (GMT)
__proto__: EventEmitter
```

Please can anyone help point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: the `key` field doesn't help you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eliezer. I'll be honest this my first time with this technology (including Mongo) so I'm more than a little confused. I was expecting to see the base64 string I could just pull out but I'll investigate using the key field further.